# How can I plot 2 figures around a node using tkz-collection in a single tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-collection

Usually I can specify a node location relative to location of another node, e.g., using `left of` and alike

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
...
\matrix (first) [left of=arrow, matrix of math nodes, ampersand replacement=\&,
  left delimiter=\|, right delimiter=\|, xshift=-2.5cm] {
...
```

Now I want to plot two simple figures using tkz-collection separated by a node with text `vs`. However I want to show same domain, i.e., I want to have same coordinates in `\tkzInit`. I thought I can isolate coordinates conflict using scope but it does not look like the case.

Is the coordinate space defined by `\tkzInit` global for entire `tikzpicture`? Shall I use overlay to somehow combine 2 figures?

Here is what I've tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=3,xstep=2, ymin=-3,ymax=3,ystep=2]
\tkzGrid[sub,subxstep=1,subystep=1](-2,-2)(2,2)
\tkzAxeXY
\node (a) at (3,0) {hello};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=3,xstep=2, ymin=-3,ymax=3,ystep=2]
\tkzGrid[sub,subxstep=1,subystep=1](-2,-2)(2,2)
\tkzAxeXY
\node[right=5cm of a] (b) at (3,0) {hello};
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I see 2 separated *hello*s but only a single figure.

Comment: Can you make your code a full compilable one by adding a few more lines?

Comment: @mlt Both scopes are typesets, on top of each other. Put for example `[xshift=6cm]` to the second scope.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Awesome! Thanks. This made a trick. Though I feel like I'm still missing all these coordinates issues how those work together with nodes. I guess I can always shift & scale tkz stuff to wherever I want.

Comment: @mlt You could also do `\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=6cm]\begin{scope}[name=scope1] … \end{scope} \begin{scope}[right of=scope1] … \end{scope} \end{tikzpicture}`. Then just put `\node (vs) at (3,0) {vs};` outside of both scopes. Though, I'm not sure how TikZ handles named scopes, `right=6cm of scope1` warns with `No shape named scope1 is known`. :(

Comment: Another thing: The node specifications `[right=of …]` and `at (x,y)` look like two conflicting settings.

Comment: I thought if I specify both it would shift scope where it supposed to be. Also it seems that tkz coordinates are different from those used by nodes, e.g., a node placed at (3,0) is not at (3,0) of plot coordinates. I wonder if there is a mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use `\xshift` option on the second scope environment. As commented by Qrrbrbirlbel, you can also remove the `at (x,y)` specification. Also, I have cleaned up the preamble a bit. `tkz-fct` automatically loads `tikz`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=3,xstep=2, ymin=-3,ymax=3,ystep=2]
\tkzGrid[sub,subxstep=1,subystep=1](-2,-2)(2,2)
\tkzAxeXY
\node (a) at (3,0) {hello};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=3,xstep=2, ymin=-3,ymax=3,ystep=2]
\tkzGrid[sub,subxstep=1,subystep=1](-2,-2)(2,2)
\tkzAxeXY
\node (b) at (3,0) {hello};
\tkzText[above,color=red](3,0){hello}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see the definition of `\tkzInit` in `\tkz-tools-base.tex`. I can't understand most of it though. :)

Also the use of `\xshift` and coordinate transformations in general are explained in page 250 of the pgf manual. It says that any specified coordinate is `first "reduced" to a position of the form "x points to the right and y points upwards." ... The next step is to apply the current coordinate transformation matrix to the coordinate."` This means that for the second scope, each original `x` coordinate is transformed.

**Update** The `tkz` collection has a command for placing text: `\tkzText`. I have modified the code with `tkzText` on the second scope just for comparison.

**Edit** I can finally say that it is not a bug. The behavior was caused by the `xstep` and `ystep` options. Here is the revised MWE. I did not delete the previous one for comparison.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=3,xstep=1, ymin=-3,ymax=3,ystep=1]
\tkzGrid[sub,subxstep=1,subystep=1](-2,-2)(2,2)
\tkzAxeXY
\node (a) at (3,0) {hello};
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[xshift=8cm]
\tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=3,xstep=1, ymin=-3,ymax=3,ystep=1]
\tkzGrid[sub,subxstep=1,subystep=1](-2,-2)(2,2)
\tkzAxeXY
\node (b) at (3,0) {hello};
\tkzText[above,color=red](3,0){hello}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any ideas as why 'hello' is not at (3,0) on the plot and how to make it happen? I'd wait with acceptance in case @Qrrbrbirlbel wants to claim points for the answer.

Comment: @hpesoj626 It's not a bug. `\node (b) at (3,0)` is a `TiKZ` command and 3 means 3cm, while `\tkzText(3,0)` is a `tkz` command where 3 means 3 tkz units which seems to be 0.5cm (I don't know why, never used it). If you use `\draw (0,0) grid (10,5)` before first scope you will see the difference.

Comment: @hpesoj626 So may be it's a bug. I've never used `\tkcFct` before testing your code. If you draw the grid you will see that `hello` is well placed according `TiKZ`. May be you could write a new question commenting it.